# return does not await async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

In the following code, `return` does not return the awaited value. What can I so the the promise will be resolved before returning. Hence I want `result` to be `SUCCESS` instead of a promise.

```js
const foo = async()=>{
    try{
        let a = await new Promise((resolve)=>{
            resolve('SUCCESS')
        })
        console.log("this is inside the try block");
        return a
    }catch{
        console.log('error')
    }
}
let result = foo();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You still need to handle the promise; `foo().then(result => console.log(result))`, for example. Async/await is just syntactic sugar for promises, it can't magically synchronise an asynchronous process.

Comment: how do I assign `SUCCESS` to result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` is an async function it will return a promise. To get the result of the promise, you will need to chain a `then` method to it:

```
const foo = async()=>{
    try{
        let a = await new Promise((resolve)=>{
            resolve('SUCCESS')
        })
        console.log("this is inside the try block");
        return a
    }catch{
        console.log('error')
    }
}

foo().then(result => console.log(result));
```

**UPDATE:**

To use the returned value, you can use it inside the `then` method or call another function with the result.

```
foo().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  //do what you want with the result here
});
```

OR:

```
foo().then(result => {
  someFunction(result);
});

function someFunction(result) {
   console.log(result);
  //you can also do what you want here
}
```

Comment: is is possible to assign `SUCCESS` to another variable, instead of just logging it?

Comment: yes, inside of the then method, or could call another callback function with the value(success)